# at most one record can be returned by this subquery ERROR

Tags: sql, subquery

```
Select  
    Query_2.[Date Assigned], Query_2.ID,
    Query_2.Aging, Query_2.[Date/Time Opened]
From    
    Query_2
Where   
    (((Query_2.[Date Assigned]) In (Select [Date Assigned]
                                    From Query_2 As Tmp
                                    Group By [Date Assigned], ID
                                    Having Count(*) > 1
                                       And ID = Query_2.ID))
    And ((Query_2.[Date/Time Opened]) = (Select Max([Date/Time Opened])
                                         From Query_2 As Tmp
                                         Group By [Date Assigned], ID
                                         Having Count(*) > 1
                                            And ID = Query_2.ID))
        )
```

Could someone help me? I couldn't figure it out what would be the error, since when I first did this, the query initially ran successfully.

Thanks in advance!

ADDED NOTE:

Basically, i tried removing the duplicate, the duplicate should be the most recent and all i want to get as unique is the first date.  i hope this is clear.  i will review the below answers later, and see if it works.  thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You have a subquery which returns multiple records in a spot which requires a single scalar value.

Comment: SELECT MAX with GROUP BY can be return more than one row

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want more easily with `row_number()`:

```
select q2.*
from (select q2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by [Date Assigned] desc, [Date/Time Opened] desc) as seqnum
      from Query_2 q2
     ) q2
where seqnum = 1;
```

This gets the record with the latest opened time on the most recent assigned date for each `id`.  That appears to be what your query is attempting to do.